# Chaining promises which read a console input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to chain some promises that which one read an input from console and passes the result to the next one into an object. The problem is I get undefined in the second promise and promises don´t chain.

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const getUrl = (objectInfo) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question('Introduce post URL ', (answerUrl) => {
            console.log(answerUrl);
            rl.close();
            objectInfo.url = answerUrl;
            resolve(objectInfo);
        });
    });
};

const getFieldsToFill = (objectInfo) => {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question('Introuce fields with spaces', (answerFields) => {
            console.log(answerFields);
            rl.close();
            objectInfo.answerFields = answerFields;
            resolve(objectInfo);
        });
    }); 
};

const getFieldsType = (objectInfo) => {
    new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question('Introduce types ', (answerTypes) => {
            console.log(answerFields);
            rl.close();
            objectInfo.types = answerTypes
            resolve(objectInfo);
        });
    });
} 

getUrl({})
    .then(getFieldsToFill)
    .then(getFieldsType)
    .then((information) => {
        console.log(information)
    });
```

Comment: I hate it when typing `return` stops working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems in your code:

1. Missing `return` statement in `getFieldsToFill` and `getFieldsType`
2. You were closing the `readline` before reading more answers

Here is the code with those fixes:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

const getUrl = (objectInfo) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question('Introduce post URL ', (answerUrl) => {
            console.log(answerUrl);
            objectInfo.url = answerUrl;
            resolve(objectInfo);
        });
    });
};

const getFieldsToFill = (objectInfo) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        rl.question('Introuce fields with spaces', (answerFields) => {
            console.log(answerFields);
            objectInfo.answerFields = answerFields;
            resolve(objectInfo);
        });
    }); 
};

const getFieldsType = (objectInfo) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log(objectInfo);
        rl.question('Introduce types ', (answerTypes) => {
            rl.close();
            objectInfo.types = answerTypes
            resolve(objectInfo);
        });
    });
}; 

getUrl({})
    .then(getFieldsToFill)
    .then(getFieldsType)
    .then((information) => {
        console.log(information)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your functions aren't actually returning the promises. They're of the format

```
const someFunction = (objectInfo) => {
    new Promise(//...
```

But should be of the format

```
const someFunction = (objectInfo) =>
    new Promise(//...
```

or

```
const someFunction = (objectInfo) => {
    return new Promise(//...
```